# Submit query to django rest api using httr in R

Tags: r, rest

I am looking to submit a query to an api within R. I've tried a few ways to format the query and have not succeeded. The django rest api has 1850 html pages. Here is an example:

```html
{
    "count": 18499,
    "next": "http://www.globallometree.org/api/v1/allometric-equations/?format=json&page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "ID_AE": 36921,
            "Species_group": {
                "ID_Species_group": 38766,
                "Group": [
                    {
                        "Family": "Combretaceae",
                        "Genus": "Anogeissus",
                        "Species": "latifolia",
                        "Subspecies": null,
                        "Species_author": null,
                        "Species_local_names": [],
                        "Scientific_name": "Combretaceae Anogeissus latifolia",
                        "ID_Family": 296,
                        "ID_Genus": 1628,
                        "ID_Species": 3838,
                        "ID_Subspecies": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            ....
      }
}
```

Each of the HTML pages begins with `count`, `next`, `previous` and `results`. Within `results` of each HTML page are 10 dictionaries (i.e. there are 10 unique `ID_AE`).
I have been able to get the full records for each html page. 
What I hope to do is query across html pages (or one at a time iteratively) within results at the lowest level. For example, I would like to retrieve all contents within results that meet a condition, such as results[Species_group][Group][Family=Combretaceae].

I've been able to return status 200 and get all of the JSON so far:

```html
 base_url = 'http://www.globallometree.org/api/v1/allometric-equations'
    resp = GET(url = base_url, authenticate(name,pw))
    parsed = fromJSON(content(resp, "text"), simplifyVector = FALSE,pretty=TRUE)
```

Also, here is [as much documentation](http://www.globallometree.org/api/docs/api-docs/api/v1/allometric-equations) as I could find on this API.